# How can I create headers for a text file and upload it with httpClient?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My text file is saved on my hard disk and I want to upload it in Visual Studio to this file management service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/content-delivery-network/quickstart#fetching-assets

Before uploading, I want to create the file headers, because I want to add a version number of the file to the headers. For example, I want to add "1" to the headers, if it is the first version. How can I do that?

After that, I want to upload the text file. But I don't know how to upload the file with httpClient. How can I upload the file?

I have tried it with this code, but it's not working and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What is wrong?

```
    private async Task UpoadNewContent()
    {
        var result = await PlayFabAdminAPI.GetContentUploadUrlAsync(new GetContentUploadUrlRequest()
        {
            Key = "Levelfiles/Level2.txt",
            ContentType = "binary/octet-stream"
        });

        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error.");
        }
        else
        {
            Uri webService = new Uri(result.Result.URL + "Levelfiles/" + "Level2.txt");
            await UploadFileAsync(webService, "/Users/myname/TESTFOLDER/Level2.txt");
        }
    }

    async Task UploadFileAsync(Uri uri, string filename)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StreamContent(stream));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

I get this response:

[image]

Comment: Have you done anything so far and got stuck? Please share your current research results and attempts

Comment: I added my code. But it's not working. I have added the response. IsSuccessStatusCode is always false.